# Delphi 11: Find correct toolsversion for MSBuild programmatically

Tags: android, batch-file, delphi, msbuild, delphi-11-alexandria

We're upgrading to Delphi 11.1 from 10.4.

We have a few scripts which build and deploy Android projects. They assemble an `msbuild` command that looked like this:

```
msbuild someproject.dproj /v:q   /p:Platform=Android /t:Build;Deploy  /p:Config=Release /p:BT_BuildType=AppStore
```

With 11.1, this throws an error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(940,7): error MSB4036: The "XmlPeek" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" directory.  [someproject.dproj]

Now, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\rsvars.bat`, which is used by all of our build scripts, explicitly sets the .NET framework as below:

```text
@SET FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
@SET FrameworkVersion=v4.5
```

After some research, I hit on the idea of adding a `toolsversion` parameter to the `msbuild` command as below, and this worked:

```
msbuild someproject.dproj /v:q   /p:Platform=Android /t:Build;Deploy  /p:Config=Release /p:BT_BuildType=AppStore  /toolsversion:4.0
```

This is all well and good, but I would prefer not to hard-code the `toolsversion` number in the script(s).

Is there a way I can programmatically obtain the correct value of the `toolsversion` that Delphi itself is using when it generates builds, etc.?

I assume that just finding the highest .NET version installed will not suffice (and even then, one has to "translate" that to a `toolsversion`). It has to marry up with whatever Delphi is doing (e.g., in the `CodeGear.Common.Targets` file referenced in the original error message).

Comment: When the `msbuild` line is run, has `rsvars.bat` already been run, or does `rsvars.bat` get run after `msbuild`?

Comment: @Magoo. rsvars.bat gets run right at the start - before any msbuild commands are issued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `rsvars.bat` has been run,

```
FOR %%v IN ("%frameworkdir%") DO SET "toolsversion=%%~nv"
ECHO msbuild ...blah...  /toolsversion:%toolsversion:~1%
```

The variable `frameworkdir` will be set by `rsvars.bat`. The `for` command parses its value (eg. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` as though it is a filename, and picks `v4.0` as the "filename" (`~n` modifier [filename] of the metavariable `%%v`)

Then use the value assigned to `toolsversion`, starting at character 1 (where the first character is "character 0")

--- Given more info in comment

```
FOR %%v IN ("%frameworkdir%") DO ECHO %%~nxv|FINDSTR /R ".*\..*\.">nul&IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET "toolsversion=%%~nxv") ELSE SET "toolsversion=%%~nv"
```

Oh ye of little faith :)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll give it a tick later (if nothing better appears). My main concern is simply that it's reliant on Microsoft being consistent in naming the Framework folders.

Comment: I was hoping for something more definitive (like a call into one of delphi's build DLLs or somesuch). But I appreciate the effort. (And of course it won't work correctly for directory names ending in e.g. v2.0, v3.5 etc - which do occur).

Comment: Consider me suitably chastened. With the latest edit, the v2.0, v3.5 etc problem no longer exists. Neat work there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Delphi 11.1 that has at least 3 bug reports: RSP-37855, RSP-38466, and RSP-38467.

You can add `/tv:4.0` to your MSBuild command line, or modify the first line in the `.dproj` file to:

```xml
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build">
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the QC reports. As indicated in question, I have added the /tv:4.0 parameter to relevant scripts and was seeking a better way of obtaining that number. Hard-coding it in even more project files would exacerbate the problem, but thanks again.